# Add html element to dynamically created div in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dynamic divs through the javascript in my asp.net mvc application. This is created in a for loop and I keep each `id` as an index value:

```
 for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
    $("<div id=" + j + "> Step " + j +  "</div>").
        hide().appendTo("#parentDiv").fadeIn();
 }
```

Now, I want to add new elements to these divs, within the same for loop. But when I am going to attach it, I am not getting the current indexed div, so that I can append it. In short, I want to render html elements dynamically in for loop on dynamically created div elements within same loop. How do I achieve this?
**Edited:**
see the real scenario is this. how to achieve?

```
 for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
    $("<div id=" + j + "> Step " + j +  "</div>").hide().appendTo("#parentDiv").fadeIn();
                    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                          $("<div id=" + i + "> Data of column " + i +  "</div>").
                         hide().appendTo("#"+j).fadeIn();
                        }

 }
```

Comment: Just an FYI: IDs that start with a number aren't valid HTML.

Comment: @Andy E just to add that this works until XHTML 1.0 but it's valid for HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
#hello{
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px; 
    background: blue;
}

.small{
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
}

.smallest{

    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;

}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {

    var div = $("<div></div>").attr({"id": "div"+j , 'class': 'small'}).appendTo($('#hello'));
    //create some variable and add to var div
    $('<div></div>').attr({"class": 'smallest'}).appendTo(div);
    $('<div></div>').attr({"class": 'smallest'}).appendTo(div);
    $('<div></div>').attr({"class": 'smallest'}).appendTo(div);
    }




});
</script>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you shouldn't assign just numbers to your ID, valid IDs begin with an alpha character.
You should be able to reference these new objects using their respective ID later in your script. The rest of your question is cryptic...

Be careful if you are trying to attach events to these, you have to use the live() method. Classic bind() or its shortcuts click(), hover(), and so on won't work on dynamicaly added elements.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a look at this : 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

this would work.

```
var count = 10
for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
    $("<div id=a" + j + "> Step " + j + "</div>").hide().appendTo("#parentDiv").fadeIn();
    $('#a' + j).html("test" + j);
}
```

Comment: added the "a" since Andy E said ids that starts with a number aren't valid. not really sure though. but i added it anyway

Comment: what is here  $('#a' + j).html("test" + j);